# How to delete character from list

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, substring

I have row,
 example : `1,2,3,5,9,7` -> not in (3,7)
 (This character need to delete  -> result select `1,2,5,9`.
 How do it ?

For example :

```
drop table test.table_4; 
create table test.table_4 (
    id integer, 
    list_id text
); 
insert into test.table_4 values(1,'1,2,3,5,9,7'); 
insert into test.table_4 values(2,'1,2,3,5'); 
insert into test.table_4 values(3,'7,9'); 
insert into test.table_4 values(5,'1,2'); 
insert into test.table_4 values(9,'1'); 
insert into test.table_4 values(7,'5,7,9');
```

query :

```
select list_id from test.table_4 where id not in (3,7)  --return 4 row

    id    list_id
1.  1     '1,2,3,5,9,7'
2.  2     '1,2,3,5'
3.  5     '1,2'
4.  9     '1'
```

How to remove 3 and 7 in row 1 and 2 ?

```
    id
1.  1     '1,2,5,9'
2.  2     '1,2,5'
3.  5     '1,2'
4.  9     '1'
```

Comment: could you set up a sqlfiddle?http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Are you asking how to remove any `7` in a string? Or are you asking how to remove the last character?  Please clarify.

Comment: @Linger or the first char not in order ^^. So many possibilities.

Comment: How to remove any "3" and "7" in a string.

Comment: Why are you storing values in a comma separated list at all? And if you want to remove `3` why does your expected output still contain it?

Comment: For example : 
drop table test.table_4;

create table test.table_4
(id integer, list_id text);

insert into test.table_4 values(1,'1,2,3,5,7,9');
insert into test.table_4 values(2,'1,2,3,5');
insert into test.table_4 values(3,'7,9');
insert into test.table_4 values(5,'1,2');
insert into test.table_4 values(9,'1');
insert into test.table_4 values(7,'5,7,9'); next ... not to include id 3,7 then select * from test.table_4 where id not in (3,7) return 4 row without 3 and 7 id , but 3 and 7 exist in list_id... how to remove 3 and 7 in list_id

Comment: **@Klevtsov Stanislav**, if you mean you want to remove any `3` or `7` in the string then why are you showing a result of `1,2,3,5,9`?  The result still has the `3` in it.

Comment: Edit your question when you have more information, don't add them as comments. This question needs a lot of explanation.

Comment: @Linger  - sorry. changed example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should deal with 3 or 7 at the start of the string, at the end of the string, or anywhere in the middle.  It also ensures that the 3 in `31` and the 7 in `17` don't get replaced:

```
select
   list_id,
   regexp_replace(list_id, '(^[37],|,[37](,)|,[37]$)', '\2', 'g')
from test.table_4
where id not in (3,7)
```

Explanation:
`^[37],` matches a 3 or 7 followed by a comma at the start of the string.  This should be replaced with nothing.
`,[37](,)` matches a ,3, or ,7, in the middle of the string.  This needs to be replaced with a single comma, which is captured by the brackets around it.
`[37]$` matches a 3 or 7 preceded by a comma at the end of the string.  This should be replaced with nothing.

`\2` is used to replace the string - this is `,` for the second case above, and empty for cases 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following statements to update all of the records.  In the below example the first statement will remove any `,7` found.  Then you execute the next statement to find any sting that has the `7` in the front of the string.

```
UPDATE test.table_4 SET list_id = REPLACE(list_id, ',7', '')
UPDATE test.table_4 SET list_id = REPLACE(list_id, '7', '')
```

If you also want to remove all occurrences of `3` then execute the following statements:

```
UPDATE test.table_4 SET list_id = REPLACE(list_id, ',3', '')
UPDATE test.table_4 SET list_id = REPLACE(list_id, '3', '')
```

However, it is a bad design to store values that you need to search agianst, work with, and etc in a string.

Comment: Data do not need to update.query that displays the string without an id 3 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexp_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) to get the expected output:

```
select  id, regexp_replace(list_id,'3,|,7', '','g') 
from table_4 
where id not in (3,7)
```

Output:

```
id  regexp_replace
1   1,2,5,9
2   1,2,5
5   1,2
9   1
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fe7d/1)